# Redhat repository server packages auto check and update

Tags: redhat, cron, yum, repository

I have Redhat repository server in my network. 
 Now just realized that my repo packages are not up to date and security updates are old too. 
 
 Is there any way to download latest packages/version to my existing repo folder? 
 
 Is there a tools or script to check update packages regularly (every week for example) and download to the local folder automatically if there is a newer version? 
 
 Thanks much.

Comment: What do you mean by "local folder"? Do you have a mirror repository?  Or are you talking about the cache folder for the RPMs?

Comment: That depends on wether or not your support supscription(s) are still valid and the method(s) you used to create a local mirror, but [`reposync` is one approved method](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016)